# Kernel and image of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}3  & 1 
\\ 1 &  -2
\\ 2  & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

and $L$ be the transformation defined by :

$$L : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3: X\mapsto AX.$$

1) Find the kernel of $L$. Is the transformation $L$ injective?

2) Find the image of $L$. Is the transformation $L$ surjective?

Comment: What have you done so far? What are the domain's dimension and the codomain's? Can a linear transformation increase the domain's dimension? What can you learn from the kernel's dimension? Show your work.

Comment: Is the formattíng correct now?

Answer (score 1):

Think of $AX$ as being a linear combination of the columns of $A$.  For if $A=[a_1, a_2]$ and $x=\left[ \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{array} \right]$, then $AX = x_1 a_1 + x_2 a_2$, where the $x_i$'s are the coefficients in the linear combination.

Since the two columns $a_1$ and $a_2$ are linearly independent, different linear combinations should give different results, i.e. $X \ne X'$ implies $AX \ne AX'$.  So the map $L: X \mapsto AX$ is injective.

Also, observe that the range of $L$ is the set of all possible linear combinations of the columns of $A$.  This is just the span of the two vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$, which is a 2-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  So the map $L$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Take an $X$ that looks like

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Than put $AX=0$ in order to find kernel. You'll get some info on $x_1$ and $x_2$ which will provide you with kernel base. If $KerL=\{0\}$ then $L$ is injective.

Considering image, I like svsring's interpretation.